# accidentally opened sublime text 3 on ~ directory, endless wheel

Tags: sublimetext3

I accidentally opened sublime text 3 on the ~ directory, it's really annoying, it only shows the wheel, and cpu is maxed out.

I think it's scanning the whole ~.

thing is if I shut and restart, that window is reopened and wheel is back.

any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to delete the `.sublime-workspace` file for your current project.

Comment: I just started it and went for a break, after some time it finished scanning and could close the folder